# Protección del campo password de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, seguridad

Seguramente no sea el descubrimiento del año, pero he caído en la cuenta que es relativamente sencillo el acceso al contenido de los campos de formulario "Password", incluso cuando la contraseña no se ha llegado a escribir (autocompletado del navegador).

Si añadimos en el inspector web, en la línea del input password:

```
onkeyup="console.log(event.target.value)"
```

En el momento que se pulse una tecla en ese campo, se muestra, en la consola de JavaScript, la contraseña.

Esto me ha alarmado un poco, porque creí que la consola del navegador podría capturar las teclas que escribíamos pero no daría el value del campo password, al menos, de éste modo tan sencillo.

No obstante, haciendo pruebas, páginas como Google protegen esto y sería interesanter saber como puede estar haciéndolo para poder implementarlo, aunque imagino que se trata de alguna solución incluso de servidor.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion pasa por el lado del servidor usando las Content Security Policy (CSP) que pueden prevenir el uso de ejecucion de scripts por parte del cliente.

Aqui podras encontrar mas información: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

**IMPORTANTE:** Ten en cuenta que con CSP simplemente podras crear por ejemplo una directiva en la que el cliente no pueda ejecutar scripts diferentes a los especificados por parte del servidor.

**El acceso a los contenidos de un campo input password seguirá siendo posible desde el propio lado del cliente.**.